# Representar precio chileno laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Necesito editar un script laravel, el precio de los productos en este momento aparece tipo: `$18,000.00` y necesito que quede: `$18.000`

¿En que archivo se puede editar esto?

Comment: Tu pregunta es bastante confusa. Te recomiendo la modifiques.

Comment: usa number_format

Answer (score 2):

La forma *correcta* de formatear un número que representa valores monetarios, en php, es el uso de la [función `numfmt_format_currency()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php), que recibe el número y el código ISO 4217 de moneda en el que debe formatearlo. Para formatear  un número que represente pesos chilenos:

```
$fmt = numfmt_create('es_CL', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$moneda = numfmt_format_currency($fmt, 18000, "CLP");
```

O este:

```
$fmt = numfmt_create('es_CL', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$moneda = $fmt->formatCurrency(18000, "CLP");
```

Anteriormente se usaba la [función `money_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), pero fue marcada como obsoleta en php 7.4 y desapareció en php 8.0, así que no hay ya razón para usarla. Lo menciono por razones históricas.

¿Qué archivo puedes editar?, no sabría decirlo, pues depende de como está hecho el sistema que tengas que corregir.

Un sistema bien diseñado tendrá una función única en la que da formato a todas las representaciones de moneda, sería de ubicar esa función y cambiar su implementación.

Un sistema mal diseñado, va a ir llamando probablemente a la función `number_format` (u otra equivalente) a lo largo y ancho de los scripts, tanto para representar números monetarios, como otros números; por lo que tocará ubicar esas  llamadas y sería un buen momento para sustituirlas por una llamada a una función centralizada que haga el trabajo, y lo haga bien  hecho, como sugiero en mi respuesta (así, mejoras el código del script también).